# OpenCV cubic vs lanzcos4 resizing

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

When resizing a matrix in OpenCV when is it appropriate to use Lanzcos4 over bicubic for upscaling?

This post cover the first 3 methods used in opencv, but it doesn't mention anything about Lanzcos4

[How do I choose an image interpolation method? (Emgu/OpenCV)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112364/how-do-i-choose-an-image-interpolation-method-emgu-opencv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lanczos4 will give results closer to the theoretical perfect filter, but you should evaluate it for your particular application. You might see some "ringing" or waves at the edges of smooth areas, and it will be slower.

You can see a good comparison of different resizing techniques at this link, although I think their implementation of Lanczos3 is implemented incorrectly for downsizing: http://pixinsight.com/doc/docs/InterpolationAlgorithms/InterpolationAlgorithms.html